# Decrypt DPAPI blob offline

Tags: mimikatz

mimikatz can decrypt DPAPI with masterkey:

```
dpapi::blob /in:"test" /masterkey:X /unprotectXXX
```

How can I dump the masterkey and do the decrypt job offline?